transform method is not being called while implementing validation pipes
I'm trying to implement a validation pipe using Zod validation library,and I don't do much different from the official docs:
I define the validation pipe:

import { PipeTransform, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ZodSchema  } from 'zod';

export class ZodValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private schema: ZodSchema) {
    console.log('Pipe constructed');
  }

  transform(value: unknown, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    try {
      console.log('Running validation pipe: ', value, metadata);
      const parsedValue = this.schema.parse(value);
      return parsedValue;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
  }
}

and I have my route handler like this:
    @Post('/google-signup')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @UsePipes(new ZodValidationPipe(GoogleSignupInputSchema))
    async googleSignUp(
        @Req() request: any,
    ) {
        console.log('Controller reached');
        return ;
    }

the schema is:
const GoogleSignupInputSchema = z
    .object({
        credential: z.string(),
    })
    .required()
    .strict();

The only two logs I get are:
Pipe constructed
...
Controller reached

I'm not really sure why the validator pipe is not being invoked. I tried placing decorators in a different order:
@UsePipes(new ZodValidationPipe(GoogleSignupInputSchema))
@Post('/google-signup') 
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)

But it shouldn't have and didn't make any differences.
The pipe does seem to work if I do something like this (in other methods):
...method2(@Body(new ZodValidationPipe(method2Schema))) {
...
}

But, in this particular case, I actually append everything to use in the app in req.data avoiding req.body at all. The body is supposed to be validated for token via api in one of the guards, and at that point, I append the validated payload to req.data, that's the flow I have, hence I'd require the @UsePipes to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I'm suggesting that you parse the body of the request
async googleSignUp(@Body() body: any) {
    console.log('Controller reached');
    return;
  }

Change the @Req to @Body

Hi there, thanks for the reply, In a way something like that did work, I've updated my question to address this case. But, in my scenerio, I actually need the UsePipe to work because of some extra decorator work

Let me be clear. You want to validate the request body. but you can't pass the Body as the method parameter in the googleSignUp ,method

yes actually, the body is supposed to be validated for token via api in one of the guards, and at that point, I append the validated payload to req.data, that's the flow I have

try changing this.schema.parse(value.body); inside ZodValidationPipe

One workaround I've resolved to for now is to create a custom decorator:
function ZVldn<T extends ZodSchema>(schema: T) {
    return function x(
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log('New descriptor is running...', args);
            const req = args[0] as Request;

            schema.parse(req.body); // handle zod exception else internal server exception
            
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, ...arguments);
            return result;
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}

I then use it as:
@Post('/route')
@ZVldn(MyZodSchema)
async myFunction(Req() _req, /* any other parameters */) {
  // controller logic
}

The trick is to expose the request object as an argument, and note this has to be the first argument or you'd have to adjust the index accordingly in the decorator logic. This would then allow to expose the request object in the argument list and hence allow to access it in the decorator.
DO NOTE: You have to keep track of which decorators you're composing though, some decorators may consume parameters, for example I could do this:
function ZVldn<T extends ZodSchema>(schema: T) {
    return function x(
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log('New descriptor is running...', arguments);
            const req = arguments[0] as Request;

            schema.parse(req.body); // handle zod exception else internal server exception
            
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, {}); // NOTE HERE !!
            return result;
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}

This would render all parameters in the controller body as undefined.
Hopefully there are better solutions, but this is kind of acceptable for now.
One thing I found noteworthy on this is since the original descriptor value is modified, the validation decorator actually runs after all decs have been executed, and also any metadata set on the descriptor value for e.g. @Post sets the 'path' metadata, is overridden depending on where the decorator is placed on the composition.
Do comment if anyone find any caveats on this approach, would love to know.
